# Postgresl : Loop a list of values to create SELECT with mulitple WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I have a simple SQL query such as

```
SELECT * from tableName
WHERE (field = 'value1') OR (field = 'value2') OR (field = 'value3') ...
```

I am lazy enough to write hardcode write the SQL query like above.
I want to extract value1, value2 , ... in an array ( or any collections)

**How to write the query above so that it can loop the list of values ?**

```
# declare array

# loop for each element in the array
SELECT * from tableName WHERE (field = element) 

# or even better
# build the WHERE clause with a loop
whereClause = (field = 'value1') OR (field = 'value2') OR (field = 'value3') ...

SELECT * from tableName WHERE whereClause
```

Comment: `where field = any(array)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are a genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name has mentioned you can

1. Check if the field is in an array

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName 
WHERE  field = ANY(ARRAY['value1', 'value2'])
```

and you can use a language of your choice to fill these values dynamically

2. or if those values are already in a table you can

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tableName
WHERE  field IN (SELECT field FROM otherTableName)
```